# Interpreting (invalid trim argument) error in R : by a newbie

Tags: r

My code is as follows:

```
lat <- 24.419
lon <- 54.502
days <- 1
Tmax <- 44.3
Tmin <- 26.0
tal <- 0.72
BCb_guess <- 0.13
epsilon <- 0.5
rad_mea <- 254
sirad::bccal(lat, days, rad_mea, extraT = NULL, Tmax, Tmin, tal)
```

When I execute my function `bccal()` from the `sirad` package, I get the following error:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I am completely new to R any help in solving the issue will be highly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is causing the error you're getting, but I think you have the `date` argument wrong. You're giving it the number of days you want to calculate for, but `bccal` (and most other functions in R) can infer this from the length of other arguments.

The `date` argument should be a vector of the actual dates you want to calculate this for. For example:

```
# for one day
lat <- 24.419
lon <- 54.502
days <- as.Date('2015-06-22')
Tmax <- 44.3
Tmin <- 26.0
tal <- 0.72
BCb_guess <- 0.13
epsilon <- 0.5
rad_mea <- 254
sirad::bccal(lat, days, rad_mea, extraT = NULL, Tmax, Tmin, tal)

# for several days
lat <- 24.419
lon <- 54.502
days <- c(as.Date('2015-06-22'), as.Date('2015-07-16'))
Tmax <- c(44.3, 43.7)
Tmin <- c(26.0, 25.1)
tal <- 0.72
BCb_guess <- 0.13
epsilon <- 0.5
rad_mea <- c(254, 253)
sirad::bccal(lat, days, rad_mea, extraT = NULL, Tmax, Tmin, tal)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have debugged this.
the bccal function is defined here .

https://github.com/cran/sirad/blob/master/R/bccal.R

the problem is coming in line 16 .

```
dtempM <- mean(as.numeric(aggregate(Zdtemp, by = format(time(Zdtemp), 
    "%m"), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)), na.rm = T)
```

specifically here

```
format(time(Zdtemp), "%m")
```

I dont really know what you want to achieve(dont have a clue about bccal ,all i can say its dependent on Tmax,Tmin and days)  ,so thats all I can do for now.
may be it would ring a bell for you

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately its been just a day since I have started using R so I am not quite aware of its syntax, do you think there is a way to go about it ?

bccal() function estimates Bristow-Campbell model coefficient ’B’ by performing a non-linear least squares regression. The output value is BCb (coefficient "B"). One of the example giving in its manual is

Its manual can be accessed at 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sirad/sirad.pdf

Comment: For a quick R tutorial -take this introductory free tutorial from Data camp
https://www.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r